# HTTP pipelining and error handling

Tags: http, sockets

Let's imagine a web-server processing a pipeline of requests and one them fails due to some reason. In what cases the server can keep the connection and in what cases it should close it?
Obviously, such errors as 403 and 404 can be handled without closing the connection. And most likely, an error will cause connection close if a part of the response has been already sent.

But what about "normal" 5xx errors? Are the popular web-server implementations tend to keep the pipelines or close them?

All info is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think in general the connection would not be closed for 5xx errors, because they are specific to the request, not the connection, so a different request on the same connection might be for another resource.

The connection should only be closed if there is a reason that it cannot stay open (like an NTLM authentication failure (401) for example, which depends on the connection). For pretty much all other reasons the connection should stay open, since the requests are independent and HTTP really has no connection semantics.

However, I have no idea what the popular web-server implementations do. If you could explain more the problem you are trying to solve (why do you care if the connection is closed or not), then perhaps we can provide more information.

Comment: What about out of memory situations? I'm implementing an HTTP server and would be glad to save some time if the others don't jump out of their pants in such cases either.

Comment: If you are implementing the server and the server cannot continue globally for whatever reason, then you can certainly close the connection.

Comment: In general, as a server you can always close the connection if you want the clients should be able to do the right thing when you do that.

Comment: Good point! Actually, I can always warn the client about it by sending "Connection: close" header along with the error message.

Comment: The problem can also be compounded if you have started to reply for a request and then you can't continue with it (let's say that the thing feeding the reply died). Anything queued up for request 2 will have to be given up; you can't start a new reply until the first reply is finished. In all situations my view is to give up on the connection. Clients should be built to be robust - networks fail. :-)